# Text to speech pronunciation is different on emulator and device

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am developing an app that read in US-EN, but notice that pronunciation is different on the emulator versus on a real device (Samsung tablet). For example, "reservoir" is pronounced something like "reserve wire" on the emulator, but correctly on the tablet. Can I rely on correct pronunciation on untested devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define correctly.  Is it aunt rhyming with "font" or aunt which sounds exactly like "ant"?  In some areas of the world its pronounced one way, in some others.  There is no such thing as globally "correct" english pronunciation (which is another word that differs-  is the middle syllable "nun" or "noun")?

As for pronunciation in general-  OEMs and users can install any text to speech they want.  So no, you can't expect it to sound a certain way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I specify that the app should use US English in each case using: engine.setLanguage(Locale.US); for both the emulator and the device. So, I expected to have control over how thing sound.

Comment: You don't get it-  there is no such thing as  a standard set of pronunciations across the US.  There's regional differences within states, let alone the country.  You're assuming that a "correct" version of spoken english exists-  it doesn't.  What you want is not possible.  Its not even desirable-  the user can install a text to speech they want, which may not match how you expect things to sound.

Comment: Thanks, but "mightochondria" is always supposed to be pronounced "mighto-kondree-ah", never "meeto-kondree-ah", but google's text to speech engine mispronounces it, and the emulator uses a third pronunciation that is also incorrect.

Comment: Get it through your head-  there is no such thing as "correct" pronunciation.  Talk to a linguist or two and get to understand language.  So no, getting something that always outputs exactly what YOU think it should is impossible-  unless you write a complete text to speech solution of your own.  And if you do, half the people who use it will think its wrong.

Comment: I've been a university professor and scientist for thirty years, so I am pretty sure that although there are no correct ways of saying things there are definitely some incorrect ways. I am writing an educational app, and teaching people nonsense is something I want to avoid. Do you know if a specific text to speech engine (Goggle's, for example) will produce uniform pronunciation independent of the device or will different devices sound radically differently even if they use the same engine and language settings? Cheers, ES

Comment: Apparently you didn't learn in your 30 years that appeals to authority are a logical fallacy.  I suggest you wander over to the linguistics department and let them laugh at you.

Comment: ANd the answer by the way is with 3rd party software who knows?  A different version of the software could have radically different output.  If you want assurances, write your own TTS app.  That's the only way to be sure of anything.  Especially since you can't force the user to have any particular TTS engine installed.

Comment: I think Steve Jobs would have disagreed with you. This has been fun. Cheers.